# Google My Business API categories problem

Tags: javascript

I am working with Google My Business API, it's my worse experience ever, according to docs try to get categories, here is my test code

```
const res = await axios.get(`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/categories`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`
      },
      params: {
        pageSize: 20,
        regionCode: 'ARE',
        searchTerm: 'test'
      }
    });
```

but every time I got "Request failed with status code 400" does it mean this URL not supported by Google at the moment or do I something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Alpha-2 country codes consist of *two* letters…

Comment: thanks for your help but I think it can't cause 400 code replay

Comment: It surely *can*. You're sending a value that's invalid as a `regionCode` as specified, which is a *Bad Request*, 400.

Comment: according to your suggestion I try to use another regionCone with two letters, the same result

Comment: you didn't provide `languageCode`.  The documentation states it defaults to English if not available, but it doesn't say the parameter is optional. Try adding `languageCode: 'en'` to your `params`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, the problem solved, I missed 'languageCode' in params, as for me google docs are not clearly enough to understand what is required in query and what not